# how to create RestController in test directory for SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-test

Im currently writing ***integration test*** for SpringBoot Application . 
It's functionality is to receive/send request from outside and forward/receive them to another application(APP_2). So there are two systems which needs to be mocked outside System and APP_2 .

[image: ProjectStructure]

**HomeController**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    ForwardController forwardController;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String greeting() {
    return forwardController.processGET().toString();
    }
}
```

**ForwardController**

```
@Service
public class ForwardController {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private ResponseEntity sendRequest(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity requestEntity, Class responseType, Object... uriVariables) {
    return restTemplate.exchange( url,  method, requestEntity,  responseType,uriVariables);
    }

    public ResponseEntity processGET()
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        String app_2_url = environment.getProperty(Constants.APP_2_URL);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = sendRequest(app_2_url,HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**APP_2_CONTROLLER**

```
@Controller
public class App_2_Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/app2Stub")
    public @ResponseBody
    String greeting() {
        return "Hello End of world";
    }
}
```

Test Class which simulates the external request behavior to the system:

**HTTP_request_Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,classes = Application.class)
public class HttpRequestTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
      assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/",
            String.class)).contains("Hello End of world");
    }
}
```

Here in this test class I'm overriding the properties by having two property file. So when we run test the request would be sent to **App_2_Controller** ( Mock in my project ) rather than the real App .

**QUESTION** :

1. Is there any way to have the APP_2_CONTROLLER inside the test folder ? This is because I don't want to expose the unwanted test endpoint in my Actual application .
2. Here in the above project , Im changing the URL with properties. Is there a better way to put a controller for the same URL. For simplicity sake lets assume, app_2 url is ***app.com:9000/serve***

Comment: Spring already have [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html). [Here is an example](https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot) . I hope it will be helps you

Answer (score 1):

Spring already comes with a [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html), that makes this a lot easier so that you don't have to create your own dummy controllers (`App_2_Controller`). So in your case, you can remove that controller, and write a test like this for `ForwardController`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ForwardControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ForwardController forwardController; // Your service

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void processGet_returnsResponseFromAPI() {
        server.expect(once(), requestTo("http://app.com:9000/serve"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("Hello End of world", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        assertThat(forwardController.processGET().getBody()).isEqualTo("Hello End of world"));
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can create a separate test for your actual controller (`ForwardController` is just a service), mock `ForwardController` and use [`MockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class HomeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private HomeController homeController;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private ForwardController forwardController;

    @Test
    public void greeting_usesForwardController() {
        when(forwardController.expectGET()).thenReturn("Hello End of world");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello End of world")));
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll end up with two tests:

1. One test to verify that `RestTemplate` is used to capture the proper response from your external REST API.
2. Another test to verify that `HomeController` just forwards whatever `ForwardController` responds.

Comment: This looks more like a WebLayer mock which is useful in unit test scenarios. In my actual application HelloController does some work and sends it to ForwardController. I was thinking about INTEGRATION TEST which covers the actual processing of whole Application itself . HelloController is my entry point to Application , ForwardController is my exit point . Is there a way to achieve this behavior in spring ?

Comment: What is the problem, in your test example ?? If you need getting response for your `forward controller` you can easily use MockServer. Spring is just example, there a lot another test libraries for creating mock servers for example [WIREMOCK](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/)